# Fake IMU for Stage?

Tags: imu, simulation, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there an implementation of a fake IMU for Stage? For example, I'd like to publish IMU readings as I teleop the simulated robot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52758/fake-imu-for-stage?/) by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3838 on 2013-01-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAIK It does not exist. In any case you can take the nav_msgs::Odometry messages sent to the /base_ground_truth topic, transform it to the IMU message and introduce manually some noise if required.

---

Originally posted by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) with karma: 2982 on 2013-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1